# How to add the rows if it is same

Tags: matlab

I have the table attached as a example image, I am trying to add the rows that have same game column. For example, for same rows like game value =0, the output should be 0.633+13.7167+16.3333. How can we do that?

[image]

Edit: I found the sum by using the MATLAB function group summary. Orig is the table name.

```
Orig{1,i}=groupsummary(Orig{1,i},"Game","sum")
```

Comment: Please post the example as code, not as an image. Also, do you want a zero result for skipped `Game` values such as `4` in your example?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Luis. I got the output by using the matlab function groupsummary :)

Comment: Glad you found it. You can post your answer for the benefit of other readers. Be sure to clarify the points I mentioned (example data as code and what to do with missing groups)

Comment: Posted. Currently I am not working on the missing groups because my data has four game ids i.e, 0,1,2,3,5. 4 not included.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as "groupsummary" was an excellent solution. However, for those poor souls using Octave, the following lines will do the same thing.

```
a=[0, 0.6333; 0, 13.7167; 0, 16.3333; 1, 0.60; 1, 10.1167; 1, 12.65; 2, 0.9833; 2, 6.7333; 3, 0.7500; 3, 5.150
0; 5, 0.0667; 5 , 0.0667]; % example matrix
>> myrowval=0;  % enter the rowvalue that should be selected
>> selrow=a(:,1)==myrowval; % create a boolean vector with "1:s" for the row with value "myrowval"
>> sum(selrow.*a)  % do element-by-element multiplication of data matrix and boolean vector, and do the summation
ans =

         0   30.6833
```